# Can jQuery/js help me determine if an URL exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out wheater or not, jQuery/Ajax can help me determine if a given URL is online.

What I really is looking for is the HTTP status code of a http connnection to the URL, but it may be too much to ask?

The urls are user input, and thus it is not possible for me to modify the environment on the server I am connecting to.

Every help is more than welcome.

Comment: jQuery.ajax, just put some code in the "failure" attribute.

Comment: Short answer, no it can't, javascript has a cross domain policy that stops it from doing cross domain requests. Long answer would be that a header check going thru something like Yahoo pipe or YQL would do that with regular JS:

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible inside of the browser but if you were to make an ajax request to your webserver, you could ask it do do the verification.

Client Code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "urltest.py",
    cache: false, 
    dataType: "text"
    success: function(data){
        if(data === "SUCCESS"){
        //do things
        } else {
        //else do other things
        }
    }
});
```

Server code

```
def call_server(self, url):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application-json'
              , 'Accept' : 'application-json'
              , 'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate'
              }
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print "SUCCESS"
    else:
        print "No soup for you"
```

Hasn't been tested or anything, but you get the idea.

Comment: 'No soup for you' -> Gold! I think I'm going to starting using this when there's an error!