# PHP Filter Var accepts some bad domains, any way to improve this?

Tags: php, regex, validation, url, filter-var

I have a form field where I want the user to enter a valid URL, so I am using `filter_var` to validate it using the `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` filter. However, it validates some pretty bad URLs, such as

```
http://www
```

is there another method for getting more accurate validation? Short of `CURLing` every URL, is the only solution to add some logic using `regex` to manually do the filtering? I am asking if there are any other built in functions to `PHP` to validate the URL, or would I have to rely on a custom method if I wanted more robust filtering?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Have you read this comment? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#104160

Comment: @Bondye: Thanks to highlight this comment! I have never read it to the end!

Comment: @Bondeye sorry but what were you referring me to, the comment about filtering unicode characters or the comment about passing multiple flags and hitting private IP ranges? I'm not sure how either relates to `http://www`'s validation.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with curl, it guarantees the user got it right. At the same time why not use some javascript too and check if url exists when user enters. I wouldn't bother with `filter_var()`, it's useless for url's.

Comment: The only thing about using curl is that it seems like unnecessary server load to curl the URL every time. And javascript can check the validity of the URL with regex, but how would I use javascript to check if the URL exists or not?

Comment: here's a [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041538/can-jquery-js-help-me-determine-if-an-url-exists) post that shows how to use js. We try to validate client and server side. client side makes it fast for the user, server side so that only expected and validated data gets through